# SQL Server communicating with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm having trouble with Visual Studio connecting with SQL Server...

From this code:

```
   #region User management
    public ActionResult SearchByRestaurant()
    {
        User objUser = new User();
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
            objUser = objContext.ContextUser.Find(id);
        }
        objUser.SearchResult = new List<SearchResult>();
        objUser.PreferencesList = objContext.ContextPreferences.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList()
        objUser.RestaurantListAll = objContext.ContextRestaurant.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList();
        if (objUser.SelectedPreferences == null)
            objUser.SelectedPreferences = new int[] { };
        return View(objUser);
    }
```

I'm getting an exception for this line:

```
objUser.PreferencesList = objContext.ContextPreferences.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList()
```

Exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Login failed for user 'sa'.

I've tried going into the settings to add the 'sa' user as a connection but it isn't working.

Further Details:

> Working with Visual Studio ASP .Net Framwork
>   Writing in C#
>   Using a basic SQL database that is already setup in VS

I really appreciate any help that can be given, and if you're willing enough to help me further please message me. Thank you!

**Update:**
I tried enabling the 'sa' account, and am now receiving this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Comment: please try opening a query tab pointing to that server and using the SA credentials you have in your code in sql server management studio to isolate if you have the right credentials.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your connection string. This is commonly set in the app.config file. Can you confirm that you have the correct password in your connection string?

Comment: I changed my credentials to a different db user, which is able to connect. I'm no longer receiving the Server Error... But I'm still receiving the same exception/error... Not sure what to do. Any suggestions? 

Exception: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't enable login by sqlserver's account

following this to enable and remember to set sa's password

https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/

Comment: No, that didn't work - and now I'm having this issue:  

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Comment: it seems logged in, but can't connect to "master" schema,
may you post your connection string?

Comment: <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContextClass" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Persist Security Info=True;database=db_FoodAllergy;User ID=sa;Password=saa"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Add this to your connection string
`Trusted_Connection=False;`